# How to extract videos frames in a folder seperately?

Tags: python, video, extract, frames

I need to extract video frames in a folder. I have 90 videos in a folder and would like to extract each video frames in a seperate folder one time.

How could I do that?

Below is the code I tried so far but it works for one video only. I would like to do this for all the videos in a folder one time:

```
    import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from glob import glob


def create_dir(path):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError:
        print(f"ERROR: creating directory with name {path}")


def save_frame(video_path, save_dir, gap=1):
    name = video_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, name)
    create_dir(save_path)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    idx = 0

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret == False:
            cap.release()
            break

        if idx == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(f"{save_path}/{idx}.png", frame)
        else:
            if idx % gap == 0:
                cv2.imwrite(f"{save_path}/{idx}.png", frame)

        idx += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_paths = glob("D:/test_/crops/*")
    save_dir = "save"

    for path in video_paths:
        save_frame(path, save_dir, gap=1)
```

Comment: If it's already working for one file, then just iterate over every file in the folder and execute your already working code on every file. `for file in os.listdir(dir): print(f"processing file: '{file}'")`.

Comment: Yes but it extracts the frames into base folder and overwrite on to first video frames if I do the same for the second video.  What I stucked is to save each video frame seperately for 90 videos.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from glob import glob


def create_dir(path):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError:
        print(f"ERROR: creating directory with name {path}")


def save_frame(video_path, save_dir, gap=1):
    name = video_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, name)
    create_dir(save_path)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    idx = 0

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret == False:
            cap.release()
            break

        if idx == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(f"{save_path}/{idx}.png", frame)
        else:
            if idx % gap == 0:
                cv2.imwrite(f"{save_path}/{idx}.png", frame)

        idx += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_paths = glob("D:/test_/crops/*")
    save_dir = "save"

    for path in video_paths:
        save_frame(path, save_dir, gap=1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).